# How are the 2 config files related?

Tags: .net, configuration

I am looking at someone else's C# code. In the project there's an **app.config** file and a **xxx.config** file, and **AppSettings** are in both of the files. But I didn't see any ConfigureSource, or build event. So how could the code use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] to access settings in both files?

Thanks.

### Some more clues:

I checked the 2 config files' properties and found that their build action are both "Embedded Resource"

### Answer Revealed!

Maybe I lack some context, this is a Visual Studio Unit Test project. The app.config and xxx.config are both embedded as resources, and during the test initialization phase, theses config files are extracted from the resource and written into the *vstesthost.exe.Config*, which is used by the *VSTestHost.exe*.

I just don't know who on earth could invent such a **un-human** solution to deal with configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] will get a value just from one file for sure (from app.config). BUT you could have 2 files with appSettings section IF app.config "redirects" to the second file:

```
<appSettings file="settings.config" />
```

and second file contains all keys.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/appsettings_fileattribute.aspx) you could read more

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But strange enough, I searched the app.config for "file=", there's none. Could there be other possibilities? Also, I searched for the "xxx.config" filename in the "app.config", also none. Thanks.

Comment: Here's some more clues. The project in question seems to put the <appSettings> and WCF <system.ServiceModel> setions in separate config file.

Comment: I don't know why your project generates 2 separate files. It doesn't seemed to be a default behavior. I would be appreciated if you could post here a short description of the solution when you find out how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can merge appSettings like this:

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="xxx.config">
    <add key="foo" value="bar"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**xxx.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="xxx" value="yyy"/>
</appSettings>
```

Note that you have to set the Copy to Output Directory property of xxx.config to **Copy always** or **Copy if newer** because xxx.config isn't copied to the output directory by default.